# Multi-threading in the same Canvas

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas

Well, I'll try to explain exactly what I pretend:

I want to draw a bitmap in a canvas in random positions according to the coordinates of the screen on touch, and I want a message(text) to be displayed everytime the user touches the screen.

So, if a draw the text in the same thread than I do for the bitmap, it will appear and dissapear right after, and I want it to stay in the screen for a few seconds and the dissapear. My first idea was to use Thread.sleep(), but for that I have to create a thread only for the text, or I will mess with the Bitmap too.

I've been trying to use multithreading in the same canvas, but I don't know how. Can someone please explain to me...

That's some of the code i've got so far:

```
private void init() {
        // CREATE SURFACEHOLDER AND ADD THIS CLASS AS HIS CALLBACK
        enemyHolder = getHolder();
        enemyHolder.addCallback(this);

        scoreHolder = getHolder();
        scoreHolder.addCallback(this);

        hasSurface = false;

    }
```

public void resume() {

```
        if (surfaceViewThread == null) {
            surfaceViewThread = new SurfaceViewThread(); // CREATE A NEW
                                                            // THREAD
            if (hasSurface)
                surfaceViewThread.start(); // START OUR THREAD
        }

        if (secondThread == null) {
            secondThread = new SecondThread();

            if (hasSurface)
                secondThread.start();
        }

    }



public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        hasSurface = true;

        if (surfaceViewThread != null)
            surfaceViewThread.start();

        if (scoreShow == 1) {

            if (secondThread != null)
                secondThread.start();
        }
    }
```

// THREAD

```
    private final class SurfaceViewThread extends Thread {
        private boolean done;

        SurfaceViewThread() {
            super();
            done = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();
            SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = enemyHolder;

            while (!done) {

                Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

                canvas.drawBitmap(enemy1, enemy1X, enemy1Y, null); // DRAW
                                                                    // FIRST
                                                                    // ENEMY




    // SECOND THREAD

    private final class SecondThread extends Thread {
        private boolean done;

        SecondThread() {
            super();
            done = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();
            SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = scoreHolder;

            while (!done) {

                Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

                canvas.drawText("xD", 50, 50, paint);

                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                scoreShow = 0;

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some incomplete pseudo code to do what you've described.  There are plenty of good examples around for each of these elements to help you fill in the blanks.

```
public class MyCustomView extends View {

     int touchPointX;
     int touchPointY;

     private String mText;

     public MyCustomView(Context context) {

         // do initialisation stuff

     }

     public setText(String text){
         mText = text;
         this.invalidate();
     }

     @Override
     public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.save();

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap(touchPointX, touchPointY, bitmap)

        if (!mText.equals(""){
            canvas.drawText(touchPointX, touchPointY + 10, mText)
        }

        canvas.restore();
    }

}

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

     private Handler mHandler = new Handler(); 
     private MyCustomView mCustomView;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           mCustomView = (MyCustomView) findViewById(r.id.myCustomView);
     }

     @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {

           // get x and y of touch
           mCustomview.touchPointX = x;
           mCustomview.touchPointY = y;
           mCustomView.setText("Screen touched");

           // clear the text after 5 seconds
           mHandler.postDelayed(clearText, 5000);


           // redraw the view
           mCustomView.invalidate();

    }

    private void clearText(){mCustomView.setText("");}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Looks a lot more clear now, but shouldn't the clearText method be a Runnable?

Comment: @Simon In the future, please edit your existing answer instead of posting a new one. You might now lose the up-vote you got on the other answer when they are combined.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use a SurfaceView?  It seems like a hard work way of doing things.

I've just done something similar by creating a custom view class and overriding the onDraw method.  Then use canvas.save() and canvas.restore().  Here's the relevant bits of my onDraw.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    canvas.save();

    // scale the canvas
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor); //, mid.x, mid.y);

    // and translate...
    canvas.translate(translateX / scaleFactor, translateY / scaleFactor);

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // draw the lights
    for(Light light:lights){
        if (light.isOn){
            canvas.drawCircle(light.getX(),light.getY(), light.getDiameter() / scaleFactor,light.paint);
        }
    }

    canvas.restore();
}
```

The lights are turned on and off by a separate thread back in the activity which has inflated the view.  They stay on screen as long as they are on.

Cheers

Comment: I thought it was the best way of doing thing, since there is some interaction with the user... So, I could just use a different onDraw method for the bitmap and the text... ?

Comment: Sure.  You can draw anything on the canvas.  See the Canvas documentation.  Take a look at the draw* methods.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

Comment: Yep, I've just tried what you said, but it draws once, but I need it to be constantly drawing a new bitmap, since the coordinates are randomly changing... Or am I missing something? 

* sorry, Im new to this...

Comment: You might find this useful  http://android-coding.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/detect-multi-touch-event-test-on-custom.html

Comment: hum, thanks, looks interesting :D I tried to use a invalidate() method at the end of the onDraw method and it works. Is it a good way of working?

Comment: I've created a thread just to draw the text so I could use the Thread.sleep(). Is there any way to draw it on the firs onDraw method Canvas? Kind of a way to access the onDraw Canvas on my thread... ?

Comment: Don't use invalidate in onDraw.  invalidate causes a redraw and therefore onDraw will be called.  invalidate is used by classes outside the view to tell the framework that a view has changed.  In the example I gave, the lights are turned on and off in a timer thread.  When they change, I call invalidate on the view to update the display.

Comment: You should only use thread.sleep in very specific circumstances.  It's not a good way of saying "do something in 5 seconds time".   In general, the way you should do this is to create class which holds your text, and any other properties of it you need.  When the text is updated somewhere else in the code, the class calls invalidate on your custom view.  There are lots of ways to do that but I would suggest making this "text" class an inner class of your view.  Or, you could make text a property of your custom view and call invalidate in a setter for that property.

Comment: Finally, there are ways to access a canvas outside onDraw but from what you've described so far, you don't need to.  I've added another pseudo code answer which might help further.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'm starting to understand what I should do and what not to do. Im testing codes based on what you said, I keep getting Force closes, but I thing I'll get it.